# How to know which app is opening when an incoming call come?

Tags: android, incoming-call

I'm using a broadcast receiver to get notified when there is an incoming call. Now I need to know if a specific app, say Facebook, is opening when the call happens to do my work.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving `BroadcastReceiver`, check the current on-screen activity which is other than `Home` screen.

To check on-screen activity, get the top activity using `ActivityManager`by getting running task list.

For example:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(2);
ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(1).topActivity;
String callHandlerPackageName = componentInfo.getPackageName();

Log.d("Call_incoming", "Call_receiver_app ::" + callHandlerPackageName);
```

You will need the following permission on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Note: the above functionality is deprecated in `Marshmallow` version. I just giving you here an example by code snippet.

Comment: I tried this code. Unfortunately, when there is an incoming call, the com.android.phone is always on top, so the code doesn't return the opening app before the call happens.

Comment: can you specify, what are you meaning by "opening app"?

Comment: It's the app was opening before the call happens. In short, I need to know if Facebook or any specified app is opening when the call come.

Comment: so, you want to know which app was opened before incoming call...right?

Comment: Yes! that's what I mean

Comment: can you replace all argument "1" by "2" like: `getRunningTasks(1)` replaced by `getRunningTasks(2)`. let me know what is the result

Comment: I changed to getRunningTasks(2) and taskInfo.get(1).topActivity and I worked! Thanks!
please update the answer so I could accept it!